# My SMS Transfer related App rejected due to Violation of Permissions policy

Tags: android, google-play, sms, android-permissions

I had submitted my SMS Transfer app on Google Play Store and I had added READ_SMS and WRITE_SMS permission in the manifest. I had selected "Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls" from Declare permissions for your app but Google rejected the app with the below information:

1. Apps with a declared core functionality for Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls can only access these permissions: READ_SMS, RECEIVE_MMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, SEND_SMS, READ_CALL_LOG. Please remove the permission(s) WRITE_SMS.
2. Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls. Please remove these permissions from your app.
3. Your app has default handler capability, which was not disclosed in the declaration form. Please remove the unnecessary capability and / or submit a revised declaration form.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

It is due to Google's restriction on SMS or Call log permission.

If you really need these permissions to fulfil certain functionalities, you should be filling 6-page [Permission Declaration Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/closedform) and submitting to Google Play for review.

Comment: Can I resubmit that form? if yes then how?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this app
it allows to send received SMS to other device or slack

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sms.pipe